What is the volume of a semiellipsoid?
(Apologies for any mistakes, English is not my first language).
Can you help me with the formula for calculating the volume of a semiellipsoid? I know that the formula for an ellipsoid is
V = 4/3 * πabc
So the formula for a semiellipsoid should be V = 2/3 * πabc, right?
I guess... I've seen it before, but I don't mean a normal semiellipsoid.
The ellipsoid equation is:
x²/a² + y²/b² + z²/c² = 1
When some people say semiellipsoid they usually cut the ellipsoid vertically, but I want it to be horizontally.
To be clear, I want the formula for calculating the volume of a semiellipsoid cut like this:
f(x,y) = c * sqrt(1 - x²/a² - y²/b²)
Or the result of rotating 180° degrees (counterclockwise) the half ellipse given by:
g(x) = b * sqrt(1- x²/a²)
See this image for clarification
Do you understand? Can somebody derive it, prove it or explain it to me in a easy way? I don't know calculus. Thank you. 

Welcome to math SE. Have a look at mathjax for your mathematical expression.

if an ellipsoid is cut by a plane   through the center of the ellipsoid,  the volume is cut in half. Indeed, the antipodal map is an isometry taking each half to the other.

The equation has second degree in $(x,y,z)$.
The cutting plane can be one of $(x-y,y-z,z-x)$, so due to an orthogonal mirror symmetry volume is divided into two equal parts.
Symmetry is not disturbed for a central conicoid (centre at the origin) cut by arbitrarily slanted planes not having symmetry about orthogonal planes. Due to such symmetry again, the truncated parts have equal volume parts $=\frac23 \pi abc$.

So, how can I calculate it in GeoGebra given my equations?

Can you  set up the volume integral ?

Unfortunatelly, I can't.
